# foreign key dynamic filter with another foreign key in admin.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

I have a problem with the dynamic design of the admin.

I want the selected productCategory to be dynamically filtered when I select the productType.

For example, I do this manually in models.py  (ProductCategory.objects.filter(productType=2 or 1 or 4 ...( i cant dynamic))
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

## models.py

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    productType = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    productType = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    productCategory = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

enter code here
```

## admin.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['productCategory'].queryset = ProductCategory.objects.filter(productType=self.instance.productType.id)


@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do same think for long time but haven't solved yet. But i can tell you why this is not work.

The problem is self.instance.productType.id is None because you have not selected yet.

Try to type print() like this and you will see why its not work.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    if self.instance:
        print(self.instance.productType.id)
        self.fields['productCategory'].queryset = ProductCategory.objects.filter(productType=self.instance.productType.id)
```